# SelectedItem of Listbox in WP7, doesnt scroll

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have 3 listboxes in a pivot page. Normaly when i write something like:
listBox3.SelectedIndex = 10;

the item is selected and is displayed. No i have the problem, that the right item is selected, but that the listbox doesnt scroll to the selected item. Does someone has an
idea what problem this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ScrollIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.

```
listBox3.SelectedIndex = 10;
listBox3.ScrollIntoView( listBox3.SelectedItem );
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work. I try to use this methods at the beginning, when i navigate to a site. But it doesnt jump to the selected verse, it just select it.

Comment: when i add a button that execute this commands, then it works. But it doesnt work for all 3 listboxes i have in the pivot page. just for two...any ideas?

Comment: @BasemAbdelfattah Where are you putting this code? Is it in the class constructor?

Comment: we may need to call UpdateLayout() before calling ScrollIntoView() as mentioned here http://wp7appdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/scrolling-to-the-selected-item-listbox/